# Python3.x ttk.Radiobutton() using

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a new in a Python.
I am using themed `ttk.Radiobutton()`. How can I change a status of my `ttk.Radiobutton() (state = "disabled" or "enabled")` in a program execution?

```
self.Menu = tk.StringVar()
self.Menu_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.root, text="Run", variable=self.Menu, value=1).place(x=2, y=25)
Menu_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.root, text="Run_", variable=self.Menu, value=2).place(x=2, y=46)
```

Comment: In a Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python says that option "state" is not supported in a ttk.Radiobutton()   https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Radiobutton.html

Comment: You can use `state` option of `ttk.Radiobutton()`, for example `ttk.Radiobutton(..., state="disabled")`.

Comment: Shure, but it means that my program will create a new component in a tkinter window every time when changing ttk.Radiobutton() state (state = "disabled"  or  "normal")

Comment: You can use `self.Menu_1.config(state=...)`.  But you need to first split the line `self.Menu_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(...).place(...)` into two lines: `self.Menu_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(...)` and `self.Menu_1.place(...)`.

Comment: because it necessary to use .place(x=x, y=y) method every time when changing a state

Comment: Thanks for answer!!!! Shure I tryed but I have an error:                   self.Menu_1.config(state="disabled")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Can you explane me why do I should split a string with creating a widget and place it in a new string????

Comment: `w = ttk.Radiobutton(...).place(...)` will assign the result of `.place(...)` (which is `None`) to `w`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change a status of my ttk.Radiobutton() (state = "disabled"
> or "enabled") in a program execuion?

```
self.Menu_1.state(["disabled"])   # Disable the button.
self.Menu_1.state(["!disabled"])  # Enable the button.

Menu_2.state(["disabled"])   # Disable the button.
Menu_2.state(["!disabled"])  # Enable the button.
```